# How to set duration on transition in barba js using animate.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using [barba.js](http://barbajs.org/transition.html) for a page transition and also im using [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css), im trying to set the duration of a transition, however the function is ignoring the duration time.

**Main.js**

```
  fadeIn: function() {
    /**
     * this.newContainer is the HTMLElement of the new Container
     * At this stage newContainer is on the DOM (inside our #barba-container and with visibility: hidden)
     * Please note, newContainer is available just after newContainerLoading is resolved!
     */

    var _this = this;
    var $el = $(this.newContainer);


        // the 300 doesn't work, it ignores it. the transition works, but it ignores the transition duration

        $el.animateCss('fadeInUp', 300, function() {

          /**
           * Do not forget to call .done() as soon your transition is finished!
           * .done() will automatically remove from the DOM the old Container
           */

          _this.done();
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: yeah it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.transitionDuration = "300ms";
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [_How do I write a good answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.